# AH01630: client denied by server configuration: Does "server configuration" mean firewall, etc. or error?

Tags: apache-2.4

When you see this error in the Apache logs - "AH01630: client denied by server configuration:" does this mean that the server is configured incorrectly so the request is throwing a 403, or does it mean that the requesting IP is blocked by the firewall or .htaccess rules?

I'm trying to figure out if this is expected behavior because we intentionally blocked an IP in our configuration, or if something is actually misconfigured.

What is my next step in researching the cause of the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error mean you have restriction for particular user. [From here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access):

> In 2.4, such access control is done in the same way as other
>   authorization checks, using the new module mod_authz_host. The old
>   access control idioms should be replaced by the new authentication
>   mechanisms, although for compatibility with old configurations, the
>   new module mod_access_compat is provided.

So you should check for configuration related to filtration based on hostname, IP address, and other characteristics of client. If you have config like:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

you should rewrite it like:

```
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is an Apache message it is an Apache limitation rather then a firewall. (If it were a firewall the packets would not get to Apache for processing)

This message is caused by a restriction in the Apache config. Googling the error should put you on the right track pretty quickly.